# Can Dojo request/iframe read response

Tags: iframe, dojo, xmlhttprequest

Receiving JSONObject but unable to read JSONOject response. It's in the body and cannot be accessed after passing a post to servlet. Why iframe, because i don't know any other way to upload file in form while using asynch. Please help. I'm really confused.

```
 require(["dojo/request/iframe", "dojo/dom", "dojo/dom-form", "dojo/dom-construct", 
   "dojo/json", "dojo/on", "dojo/domReady!"],
 function(iframe, dom, domForm, domConst, JSON, on){

 on(dom.byId("startButton"), "click", function(){

  iframe("addUser",{
  form: "myForm",Ca
  handleAs:"json",

  }).then(function(response){   
  alert(response);
  alert("data received!");    

  }, function(err){    
  alert("data denied!!!");    
   alert(err);
```

*************************** Servlet JSON response********************************

```
      JSONObject cert = new JSONObject();
        cert.put("version", x509certificate.getVersion());
        cert.put("valid from", x509certificate.getNotBefore());
        cert.put("valid to", x509certificate.getNotAfter());
        cert.put("issuer", x509certificate.getIssuerDN().getName());
        cert.put("Thumbprint", getThumbPrint(x509certificate));

        System.out.println(cert);
        System.out.println(cert.toString());
        out.print(cert.toString());
```